# script that would just go through all css files and change every .classname to .class-name

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

Of course after changing each css query in the file and replacing _ with - it would simultaneously be changing all other files where the said query is being used.

So if .bold_7 is changed in css to .bold-7 then it should also be changed in HTML/Javascript files that it was used in.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about in your editor? Like it you edit the CSS file, it updates all the other files? Seems like a job of find and replace...

Comment: damn yep, alright well i dont know why i thought i need a script for this. 

Although with search and replace i guess i need to do it one by one which is actually fine coz i can check if something got broken.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is just use Search and Replace of the editor.

Probably best 1 by 1 since just changing _ to - might mess up something in javascript.